# Programatically get category collection by multiple root category id

Tags: category, programmatically

I am working on a script, my requirement is to get child categories of multiple root categories. Root category is an array of ID's.

Example: `$myrootcats = array('12,15,18,20')`;

And I want all active categories which belong to the above array.

Comment: I don't know why you asked the same question twice but I vote to close the old one because the new one is in better form

Comment: You have not tagged this as magento 1 or magento 2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code to get all subcategories.

```
<?php
$myrootcats = array('12,15,18,20');
$catArray = array();
foreach ($myrootcats as $_rootCat)
{
    $children = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCategories($_rootCat);
    foreach ($children as $category)
    {
      if($category->getIsActive()){
        $catArray[] = $category->getId();
      } 
    }
    $catArray[] = $_rootCat;
}
array_unique($catArray);
```

Comment: It is also give me inactive subcategory.

Comment: edited my answer. Added condition for check is active.

Comment: Yes working correct....

Answer (score 0):

```
$myrootcats = array('12,15,18,20');
foreach($myrootcats as $myrootcat) {
    $cat = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($myrootcat);

    /*Returns comma separated ids*/
    $subcats = $cat->getChildren();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you want to  ***filter category  by root category id*** then you can use ***path category attribute path becuase magento save save root category in path***.

> ```
> require_once "YOurMagentoDirapp/Mage.php";
> umask(0);
> ini_set('display_errors', 1);
> Mage::app("admin");
>
>
> $buildArray=array();
>
> $rootId = Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::TREE_ROOT_ID;
> $rootids= array(12,15,18,20);
>
> foreach($rootid as $id){
>
>   $buildArray[]= array('attribute' =>'path','like'=>$rootId.'/'.$id.'/%');
>
> }
>
> $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
>         ->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1)
> ->addFieldToFilter($buildArray);
> ```

If want to ***immediate child category of root categories***  then just change ***logic of  $buildArray***

> ```
> foreach($rootid as $id){
>
>  // $buildArray[]= array('attribute' =>'path','like'=>$rootId.'/'.$id.'/%');
>    $buildArray[]= array('attribute' =>'parent_id','eq'=>$id);
>
> }
>
> $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
>         ->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1)
>
>         ->addFieldToFilter($buildArray);
>             ->addFieldToFilter($buildArray);
> ```

Comment: there are some mistake..now you see update