# Programatically get subcategories of several root categories with collection

Tags: category, collection, collection-filtering

I am working on a collection query of categories:

```
$categories_check = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')
    ->getCollection()               
    ->setStoreId($storeId)           
    ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)       
    ->addAttributeToFilter('path', array('like' => "1/{$rootCategoryId}/%"))   
    ->setProductStoreId($storeId)   
    ->setLoadProductCount(1)   
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
```

It returns the categories below root category `$rootCategoryId`. My requirement is to change this query, that it works for an array of root categories.

Like when I pass the array `$rootcat = array('15,20,25,35');` it provides me categories below these root categories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Edited:

As basic of on your last question [Programatically get category collection by multiple root category id](https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/85440/4564) .I have give you the answer.

Have create ***multiple OR  condition for  addFieldToFilter()*** for getting the result  ***on basic of path field***

You should this script which may be give u your required result.

> ```
> require_once "YOurMagentoDirapp/Mage.php";
> umask(0);
> ini_set('display_errors', 1);
> Mage::app("admin");
>
>
> $buildArray=array();
>
> $rootId = Mage_Catalog_Model_Category::TREE_ROOT_ID;
> $rootids= array(12,15,18,20);
>
> foreach($rootid as $id){
>
>   $buildArray[]= array('attribute' =>'path','like'=>$rootId.'/'.$id.'/%');
>
> }
>
> $collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection()
>         ->addFieldToFilter('is_active',1)
> ->addFieldToFilter($buildArray);
> ```

***For getting  the query of a collection.You can try this.***

`$CollectionObject->getSelect()->__toString();`

**For you case. use below**

> echo $categories_check->getSelect()->__toString();

Donot use

- ->setStoreId($storeId)
- ->setProductStoreId($storeId)
- ->setLoadProductCount(1)

Comment: I want this query also work for array of root category and give it sub category.

Comment: do you have try my  yesterday answer  http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/85448/4564

Comment: i have check his/her last question on basic of  that o have asnwer this question

Comment: Why not use above condition in collection "->setStoreId($storeId)" etc.

Comment: if i use then it may be one store wise collection.. not sure 100%. Was not tried yet'

Comment: How we can filter products on array of website ids and array of store ids see this question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/86114/programatically-get-product-collection-which-are-exists-in-array-of-website-ids....

Answer (score 2):

You can pass an array of conditions to `addAttributeToFilter`, then it will be combined with `OR`.

The syntax is as follows:

```
->addAttributeToFilter(array(
    array('attribute' => 'path', 'like' => "1/15/%"),
    array('attribute' => 'path', 'like' => "1/20/%"),
    array('attribute' => 'path', 'like' => "1/25/%"),
    array('attribute' => 'path', 'like' => "1/35/%"),
))
```

Create this array parameter with a loop over your input array and you are set.